# fread cannot read new line added

Tags: php

i have this code to write line into new.txt(already consist of 2 line) file and after that copy(backup) this txt content into new tmp.txt file
but the fread() keep missing the new line from new.txt file to copy into tmp.txt
tmp.txt suppose to have 3 line inside, but the new added line missing.

```
$File ="new.txt";
$File2="tmp.txt";


//write into file
$handle = fopen ($File, 'a') or die("Cannot open File");    
fwrite($handle,"some string");
fclose($handle );

//copy file
$handle2= fopen ($File, 'r') or die("Cannot open File");
$content = fread($handle2, filesize($File));
fclose($handle2);   

$handle3 = fopen ($File2, 'w') or die("Cannot open File");  
fwrite($handle3,$content);
fclose($handle3 );
```

Comment: use `\r\n` or `\n` for newlines

Comment: i have successfully added new line into new.txt file, new.txt become 3 lines,but the problem is to copy from new.txt into tmp.txt after write new line, i only got 2 lines

Comment: Possible filesize gotcha.... try issuing a clearstatcache() call  - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php - after closing the file after your initial write

Comment: What is the relevance to HTML?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit sorry i didnt mention that i am using Select option in my html page to display those text content, anyway i already got the answer,thank's to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation for `filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php):

> **Note:** The results of this function are cached. See [`clearstatcache()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.

Following that link, you get the following additional information, which answers your question completely:

> When you use [stat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php), [lstat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lstat.php), or any of the other functions listed in the affected functions list (below), PHP caches the information those functions return in order to provide faster performance. However, in certain cases, you may want to clear the cached information. **For instance, if the same file is being checked multiple times within a single script, and that file is in danger of being removed or changed during that script's operation, you may elect to clear the status cache. In these cases, you can use the `clearstatcache()` function to clear the information that PHP caches about a file.**

The documentation is your friend; use it!

Answer (score 0):

The command fread() takes as second argument the *length* of the content to read and not the file size which isn't the same thing. 
Anyways it'll be better to use copy() instead of fread() to duplicate the file:

```php
//replacement for your copy file
copy($handle1, $handle2);
```

Comment: `the length of the content to read and not the file size which isn't the same thing` What is the difference? (cache notwithstanding)

Comment: When you have 10 characters inside your file the length is 10 but the file size may be 1 kilobyte or something ;)

Comment: thanks Hexodus, it work i added clearstatcache(); function into my line, it seems that it still hold old filesize value

Comment: @Hexodus: No - don't confuse "file size" for "block size * block count". http://stackoverflow.com/q/16438142/560648

Comment: Excuse my half-knowledge and thanx for the link - good to know it.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit because i got the idea about file size length from this answer