# Why am I getting such accurate results from `filesize`?

Tags: php

When I run this code:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('/tmp/lolwut', 'w') or die("Cannot open File");    
fwrite($handle, "1234567890");
fclose($handle);

print_r(filesize('/tmp/lolwut'));
?>
```

I get the result `10`, which is the correct number of characters in the file.

However, because filesystem blocks are much larger than this, I expected the file size to be "rounded up" to more like 512 bytes or even 1KB. Why is it not?

Comment: _This question is designed to address [a misconception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435318/fread-cannot-read-new-line-added/16435725?noredirect=1#comment23572278_16435725)._

Comment: good question for the com. wiki, but 1. what does your link have to with this question? (it's about cache) and 2. Wouldn't a better title be *Why does `filesize` return a smaller size than the file uses?* or something like that?

Comment: @dtech: It's a link to a comment. Read the comment.

Comment: Possibly a community wiki question?

Comment: There is no need to force this to be a CW and deny some one the recognition for hard work. That said, I would suggest remaining the question, it doesn't seem to come across as something someone would genuinely ask. I suggest something along the lines of "How come `filesize` does not agree with the file size on disk?"

Comment: @MarkBaker: Why's that?

Comment: @thecoshman: I genuinely asked it, _just now_!

Comment: Because I consider CW as the repository for "definitive" answers... I don't begrudge LRiO the rep (or a "self learner" badge) for it, and I'm only suggesting it as CW because it is a Q&A with one true answer, and therefore "definitive"

Comment: @MarkBaker: Anyone is welcome to submit their own answers to this question, just like any other question! It's not up to you or me to decide that my answer, which happened to be first, must be the correct or "definitive" answer. Certainly community wiki is not a feature designed to allow us to pretend that we should do that.

Comment: It's difficult for anyone else to provide an answer without simply repeating what you're said :) .... about the only thing I might be able to add that you haven't covered is the "beware of the statcache" gotcha.... and I've upvoted both question and answer

Comment: @MarkBaker: That's just because I wrote a good answer, not because of any property of the question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not confuse "file size" for "file size on disk"; [PHP's `filesize` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) gives you the former, not the latter.

Although not explicitly documented as such, `filesize` is basically implemented in terms of `stat`, and on Linux [`stat` makes a distinction between filesize and "file size on disk"](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat):

> All of these system calls return a `stat` structure, which contains the following fields:
>
> ```
> struct stat {
>     // [...]
>     off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
>     blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
>     blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
>     // [...]
> };
> ```

The value you're expecting is `st_blocks * st_blksize`, but the "true" filesize `st_size` is available regardless.

([This appears to be the case on Windows, too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).)